# I want to insert multiple rows in mysql by php

Tags: php, sql

I want to insert multiple values into database , my value are coming from database, but when ever i am inserting it is not throwing an error but it was inserting Array till loop repeat.
Please guide me..
Code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="" name="name[]"/><?=$name;?></div>
<input type="hidden" id="" name="class[]"/><?=$class;?></div>
```

php code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
@session_start();
$sessionName = $_SESSION['NAME'];
$date = date('d-m-y');
$loc= $_POST['locationID'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$status = $_POST['status'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$section = $_POST['section'];
for( $i = 0; $i < count($loc); $i++ )
{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_attendence (fld_studentname,fld_status,fld_class,fld_section,fld_date,fld_takenby)
            VALUES ('$name','$status','$class','$section','$date','$sessionName')";
        //echo $sql; exit;

    mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

please guide me ... i am getting Array in all columns .

Answer (score 1):

### Why your code is not working

You're telling PHP to put input values into an array.

### Inputs will be empty

If you want to set the values coming from PHP, you have to use

```
value="<?php echo $name; ?>"
```

### Solution

Just replace

```
<input type="hidden" id="" name="name[]"/><?=$name;?></div>
<input type="hidden" id="" name="class[]"/><?=$class;?></div>
```

With

```
<input type="hidden" id="" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="" name="class" value="<?php echo $class; ?>" />
```

Comment: Is type=hidden no longer valid? Or you just don't know about it?